# Editing Objects with PropertiesGrid (C#/WinForms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a class called ANSFile that I wrote which I want to make editable from a propertiesgrid. That class has properties including a list of ANSJoints, another class I wrote. That ANSJoints class has a property of the type ANSPoint, a third class I wrote.

I want to be able to edit the ANSPointof a Joint in the ANSFile's collection from a propertygrid. I have the form implemented:

[image]
[image]

But the ANSPoint property is not editable. How can I change the ANSPoint class to be editable in the grid?

ANSDistance source

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class AnsDistance
{
    public double Length { get; set; } //Value of the distance being stored
    public DistanceType Type { get; set; } //Type of the distance being stored

    public AnsDistance()
    {
        this.Length = 0.0;
        this.Type = DistanceType.Inch;
    }

    public AnsDistance(double passedLength, DistanceType type = DistanceType.Inch)
    {
        this.Length = passedLength;
        this.Type = type;
    }

    public AnsDistance(Distance passedDistance, DistanceType type = DistanceType.Inch)
    {
        this.Length = passedDistance.GetValue(type);
        this.Type = type;
    }

    public override string ToString() //Returns the value of the distance rounded to two decimal places
    {
        return Math.Round(this.Length, 2).ToString();
    }
```

ANSPoint source

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class AnsPoint
{
    public AnsDistance X;
    public AnsDistance Y;

    public AnsPoint(AnsDistance passedX, AnsDistance passedY)
    {
        this.X = passedX;
        this.Y = passedY;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.X.ToString() + ", " + this.Y.ToString();
    }
}
```

Partial AnsJoint

```
 public class AnsJoint
 {
     public AnsPoint Location { get; set; } //Point made of values found under X and Y Coordinates columns
 }
```

Comment: Updated question, realized I gave the wrong class too lol

Comment: Just added a TypeConverter. Its better in that an arrow now appears so I can expand ANSDistance but hitting the arrow just makes it go away so its still not working

Comment: I appreciate the link, but i already added a typeconverter and like I said it doesnt show the individual values when I hit the arrow like his does, for me the arrow just vanishes

Comment: I realized I need a custom TypeConverter, wrote one and now it works

Comment: Actually even better, turns out I forgot to make X and Y properties...so simple